# Two aliens hit a human while riding along a road

Tags: story-identification

Published before 1976.  Involves 2 individuals riding along in a vehicle of some sort when they hit and kill a creature on the road.  At first it appears two people killed a deer or something, but it turns out that earth has been overtaken by technologically advanced aliens and in fact the aliens hit and kill a human on the road.  They feel sad, but horrified.

Ring any bells?

Comment: This does sound a little bit like Lem's _Invasion from Aldebaran_, although you would have to have a few facts wrong in order for this to be what you're after. The story (I've only found Polish and German versions online), roughly described, is about two (Slavic) backwater village inhabitants stumbling home stark-drunk and, without even realizing it, deflecting the invasion of the mighty Aldebarans (which have already conquered half the galaxy because no other planet could withstand their advanced technology) by inadvertently liquidating the scouts who had previously landed besides the way.

Comment: I remember this story, but not the title or author.  I'd have to guess it was a short story in Analog sometime in the late 1970s, but it is just a guess.  I remember two green humanoids in a vehicle hitting a creature that looks something like them, but it isn't green.  I believe the hook was that the people in the vehicle were the genetically modified descendents of true humans who now rule the planet, and they'd hit one of the last normal humans living in the wild.  They ate him.

Comment: "They feel sad, but horrified"? Odd use of "but". Did you mean to write "sad, but *not* horrified"?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

> [10:01 A.M.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45493), by Alexander B. Malec 1966, originally published in *Analog
> Science Fiction - Science Fact*: A couple of punks, Poxie and Slick,
> were on their way to Albuquerque from Chicago in a run of the mill
> flying car. Safety regulations prohibited anyone from operating a
> flying car below four meters and every flying car in the sky had
> multiple, redundant and undefeatable systems built in to prevent them
> from descending below that altitude, except when landing on special
> pads. At least, that's the theory. Because they have figured out how
> to jimmy the safety devices, Poxie is flying the car at two meters so
> that he can speed. In a suburban neighborhood Poxie struck an eight
> year old girl, killing her immediately. The two left the scene as
> nonchalantly as they could, then stepped on it to escape.

Found on [Omphalos' Book Reviews](http://www.omphalosbookreviews.com/index.php/reviews/info/315)

Comment: Probably not. It doesn't seem (from the review--I haven't read the story) that Poxie and Slick are aliens, or that the reader is initially led to believe the victim was a deer.

Comment: Moreover, it appears from Omphalos' review (of which you quoted only the first paragraph) that the story is mainly about the arrest, trial, and punishment of the two punks. I think the OP would have had something about that in the question.

Comment: That was one tall eight year old girl